# Service fabric. Deploy multiple applications with different configurations

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric, azure-deployment

Im trying get three or more applications running with Service Fabric. They would all use same api services, only difference would be that each of them would get configurations from different storages. What would be the right way to pass the correct connection string without using environment variables?

Comment: Have you referred to this article: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-multiple-apps.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your configuration parameters for each SF application under the application's ApplicationPackageRoot/ApplicationManifest.xml file, then specify the parameters in the "ApplicationParameters" folder for your publish profiles.  More info on this approach can be found here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-manage-multiple-environment-app-configuration